# Shell Not Able read files written with python

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, files

I made a python file which tells every .java file in the folder it is placed in and you can select which java file to execute, the selected java file's name is then written in a file named Input.txt, But i cannot read that file in shell:

My Python File:

```
import glob, os
import sys
a=sys.path
count=0
os.chdir(a[0])
ifile=open("Input.txt","w")
i=1
for file in glob.glob("*.java"):
    if(count%2==0):
        print(i,".",file,end="")
        g=str(i)
        l=len(file)+len(g)
    else:
        print("".rjust(40-l,' '),i,".",file)
    i=i+1
    count=count+1
print("")
flag=1
while flag==1:
    f=int(input("Enter The File No. You Want To Execute:"))
    i=1
    for file in glob.glob("*.java"):
        if(i==f):
            flag=0
            x=file
            break
        i=i+1
    if flag==1:
        print("File Not Found!!\nPlease Enter Again:")
ifile.write(x)
ifile.close()
```

The shell file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bashs
echo WELCOME TO EXECUTOR
echo Garvit Joshi\(garvitjoshi9@gmail.com\)
echo USER:$USERNAME
python3 Filename_java.py
filename="Input.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
        echo "$line"
done <"$filename"
exit
```

[image: Output OF .sh file]
edit 1:Please Do not go through algorithm of python file.It works fine.

Comment: `/bin/bashs` isn't a valid interpreter.

Comment: @Kulfy what should i write there?

Comment: Remove the extra `s` after `/bin/bash`. Also, `javac` only compiles Java code, i.e., converts it into Byte Code. If you want to run the Java code, you can use `java "$line"`  (IIRC this feature was introduced in JDK 10 or 11).

Comment: Still Does Not Show The File Written In Input.txt. I Have Erased that line and added the output. My main problem is with$line does not contain anything, while the Input.txt has text written in it.

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: @Kulfy JDK 8, The Problem lies that ```line``` does not contain anything.

Comment: @GarvitJoshi are you sure that `line` does not contain anything? Your python code does not appear to add a terminating newline - so `read` will exit with non-zero status despite reading data. Either add the newline (to make `Input.txt` a POSIX-valid text file) or change your shell read command to `read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]` so that the loop body is executed provided it reads data even if `read` fails.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver It worked. As I am new to this community, should i write the answer or leave this thread like this only.

Comment: @GarvitJoshi since we appear to have solved the problem, I have added an answer for your consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please Do not go through algorithm of python file.It works fine.

Well yes - but actually no. It writes the characters of the filename, but doesn't terminate the string with a newline.

The shell's `read` command expects to read complete lines, and returns a non-zero exit status if it does not do so. Hence `while IFS= read -r line` does not execute the loop body.

You should either modify your python code to write the terminating newline, or modify your shell code so that the loop body tests for a non-empty line as well:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do ...
```

See for example [Why does this 'while' loop not recognize the last line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482525/65304)

Comment: Thanks, I just added ```ifile.write("\n");``` .